# How to adapt Chromium web application launcher for Snaps?

Tags: launcher, chromium, snap, 19.10

I updated to 19.10 from 19.04, and a custom web application launcher that uses Chromium no longer works properly. Just a guess, but this may be because Chromium is now a Snap package (and no longer a deb package, which was uninstalled during the update).

How do I adapt my `.desktop` file to restore the previous functionality, which used a dedicated icon and launched a separate instance of Chromium that operated independently of the default one?

Here's the file that used to work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=TweetDeck
StartupWMClass=tweetdeck.twitter.com
Exec=chromium-browser --class tweetdeck -user-data-dir=~/.config/tweetdeck --app=https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/ %U
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=~/.local/share/applications/tweetdeck.svg
StartupNotify=true
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser
```

Comment: This seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1732482).